# Throwable method overriding in Java

Tags: java

First, sorry for my bad english.
Question:
If I have a subclass that extends a method which throws a CHECKED Exception, why Java's allow's me to throw a RuntimeException in the subclass's overriding method like the example below:

```
public class A {

    public void doSomething() throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("doing something...");
    }
}
```

And then...

```
public class B extends A {
    public void doSomething() throws RuntimeException { // <- my question
            System.out.println("doing something here too...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `RuntimeException` is not a checked exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any method can throw `RuntimeException` or `Error` - the unchecked exceptions base classes. So the `throws RuntimeException` is irrelevant to anything else.

You can override a method with a narrower throws clause. The `throws FileNotFoundException` does not imply the method must throw the exception. The method in the base class may throw it; the method in the derived method does not in this case.

You can't widen the throws clause because client code with a reference to the base class would not be expecting it.

This is similar to *covariant return types* where you can narrow the return type of method in a derived class/interface.

Answer (score 4):

The whole idea about these restrictions is that a subclass should not force callers to catch another type of checked exception than the one(s) specified by the overridden method declaration (be it a broader one or a completely unrelated one).

In your case:

- `throws FileNotFoundException` is completely omitted in `B.doSomething`: this is fine (it would also be fine if the subclass's method declared to throw a subclass of `FileNotFoundException`). There would be a problem if `B.doSomething()` declared `throws IOException` or something completely unrelated, like `throws SqlException`.
- `throws RuntimeException` is declaring that it can throw an unchecked exception. Callers are not forced to catch unchecked exceptions anyway, so this wouldn't break any code written to call `A.doSomething()`