# Why does this compile? Overriding method not a subclass of exception

Tags: java, exception

I have a hard time to understand why the following code compiles, while it is not a subclass of exception:

```java
class Test 
{
    public void run() throws IOException 
    {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}

class SubTest extends Test 
{
    //not a subclass of IOException, still compiles 
    public void run() throws RuntimeException 
    {
        System.out.println("Test from sub");
    }
}

class Sub2Test extends Test 
{
    //not a subclass of IOException, does not compile
    public void run() throws Exception  
    {
        System.out.println("Test from sub");
    }
}
```

I understand `RuntimeException` is an unchecked exception, but I thought the rule was that it must be a subclass of the parent exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Throwable method overriding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56590114/throwable-method-overriding-in-java)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663701/what-is-the-criteria-for-throwing-exceptions-in-subclass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **"I understand RuntimeException is an unchecked exception, but I thought the rule was that it must be a subclass of the parent exception?"**

That is the general rule, as specified in the JLS in section [§11.2. Compile-Time Checking of Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2), which states (emphasis mine)

> The throws clause of an overriding method may not specify that this method will result in throwing **any checked exception** which the overridden method is not permitted, by its throws clause, to throw ([§8.4.8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3)).

But that only applies to checked exceptions, and it also explicitly states that

> The unchecked exception classes ([§11.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1)) are exempted from compile-time checking.

So the compiler is going to ignore the fact that `RuntimeException` isn't a subclass of `IOException`.

Answer (score 8):

Imagine there is a caller which calls `Test#run`. In the declaration of `Test#run`, it says it might throw `IOException`, so the caller knows it can catch and handle it:

```
Test test = // it could be instance of SubTest of Sub2Test
try {
   test.run();
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

Then it's ok if `SubTest` does not throw `IOException`, the caller will not miss anything.

But if you throw some checked `Exception` like `Sub2Test`, since the caller does not know it until runtime, the called is not able to catch and handle it. So it should not be compiled.